# how to upload Data to API?

Tags: ios, swift, api, upload

I need to upload Data to API. Parameters:
[image: ScreenShot]
I have next code:

```
static func uploadNewInfo(uploadData: Data) {
        if let url = URL(string: TaskManager.httpString + "sett_eic.htm") {
            var request = URLRequest(url: url)
            request.httpMethod = "POST"
            request.httpBody = uploadData
            request.setValue("multipart/form-data", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
                if error == nil {
                    print("uploaded")
                }
            }
//            let task = URLSession.shared.uploadTask(with: request, from: uploadData) { (data, response, error) in
//                if error == nil {
//                    print("uploaded")
//                }
//            }
            task.resume()
        }
    }
```

But response is `"500 Internal Server Error: Expected data not present\r\n"`
I don't understand how can I upload this data. I read some answers about how to upload Image, but don't understand it. My data is not Image. It's bytes, which describes Names, states, etc.

**Update**

This is how request looks in browser:
[image: Screenshot2]
Part with PRF64... - uploadData

Comment: What is in `uploadData`?

Comment: @Ladislav, this is strings converted to Data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
func uploadNewInfo(uploadData: Data) {
    let boundry = "**********"
    if let url = URL(string: TaskManager.httpString + "sett_eic.htm") {
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        //        request.httpBody = uploadData
        request.addValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundry)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        var dataForm = Data()
        dataForm.append("\r\n--\(boundry)\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
        dataForm.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"param1\";\r\n\r\n10001".data(using: .utf8)!)
        dataForm.append(uploadData)
        dataForm.append("\r\n--\(boundry)--\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
        request.httpBody = dataForm

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            if error == nil {
                print("uploaded")
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

Please let me know if it works :)

Comment: I'm tried, but also not works. I don't understand why.

Comment: Maybe something is wrong with your URL. Because I sent request with this code and it gave success on my URL.
Can you share your URL?

Comment: there is little mistake in your code. I fixed it, apply and it is works.

Answer (score 0):

you can use **[Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire)** :

```
 func UploadData(uploadData: Data){
let paramter = ["data":Data]
let Header = ["Authorization":"Bearer ..."]

Alamofire.request("", method: .post, parameters: parameter, headers: Header).responseJSON(completionHandler: { (response) in

guard let value = response.result.value as? NSDictionary

}
```

Comment: thanks for answer, but I don't use Alamofire in my project now